# App always shown in Taskmanager

Tags: android

Whenever am pressing device back button my Main Activity life cycle happens as normal and app gets closed. When i go to Task manager, its showing my Application and clicking starts new MainActivity life cycle. I didn't use any launch mode.

Comment: why dont you accept answers for your questions?no answers help you? accepting question is a motivation for others to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Back button just pops up your Activity from Back stack and doesn't kill your Application Process

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior. An application doesn't get closed unless the user manually does it in the task manager (Android 3+) or Android settings, or if Android closes it to reclaim memory.

Answer (score 0):

Override [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) method and call [finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) inside it to finish your activity.
Hope this helps !